# vb net rdlc slow to preview

Tags: .net, vb.net, rdlc

I have a vb net program write using VS 2015 which displays a RDLC report and when I run it with in VS it opens and the report preview opens very quickly and is useable.
When I move the EXE file and the other associated file to a folder and run the exe and a standalone program then the program starts ok but the RDLC report takes about 20 seconds to load the preview which is about 15 sec longer that when I run the same program in VS.

I have added this to the app.config file as I have:

```
<runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

The project is set to Net 4.5
I am using Visual Studio 2015

As it is the report is useless as it takes so long to open can anyone help with this I would have thought it would run slower in VS with all its overhead

Answer (score 2):

The solution was yo update the Ref to microsoft.reportviewer.common.dll and microsoft.reportviewer.winform.dll to version 12 in VS project properties.

Don't forget to include .exe.config file with your distribution as you still need to add

```
<runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

to the app.config otherwise the time performance is just dreadful.

Hope this will help others